# Getting one word from given string

Tags: vb.net, string, substring

I have the following strings: `Anaheim Temp. 1-N/A` and `Cevera-N/A`.

How do I get `Temp` from the first one and `Cevera` from the second one?

So sorry,I'll try to provide more info: So lets say I want to split the first string to first name and last name so first name would be "Anaheim" last name would be "Temp" second example: "Alex Orellana-NA" so first name would be "Alex" last name "Orellana" how do I get rid of whats coming after special characters like "-" "." "/"

Comment: Do you mean, how do you detect if a string contains a given string? Your existing question doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I'm just asking here is a given string Anaheim Temp. 1-N/A" how do I get "Temp" from that string? Also there is another string "Cevera-N/A" How do I get----> "Cevera"

Comment: It is impossible to help you with these informations. Please give us the standard you are using to manipulate these strings.

Comment: Your requirements are missing. Based on your question it could just be: "Anaheim Temp. 1-N/A".Substring(8, 4), "Cevera-N/A".Substring(0, 6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you are asking for. You are looking for a function that will take 2 strings and search one string with a phrase, then return the result if it contains it. I believe I have a solution to your issue:

```
Public Function FindCertainString(stringToSearch As String, stringToFind As String) As String

    For index = 1 To stringToSearch.Length - 1

        Dim character As Char = stringToSearch(index)

        ' Parse through whole string and find any match values

        If character = stringToFind(0) Then
            ' Matched the first letter

            Dim tempIndex As Integer = index
            Dim someWord As String = ""

            For innerIndex = 1 To stringToFind.Length

                someWord += stringToSearch(tempIndex)
                tempIndex += 1

            Next

            If someWord = stringToFind Then
                ' Found the word you were looking for
                Return someWord
            End If

        End If

    Next

    Return ""

End Function
```

This should satisfy what you are looking for because what this function will do is take in the two strings then for the `stringToSearch` it will prase through each character until it identifies a match to the beginning letter in the `stringToFind` from there it collects together an equal length in characters and examines if it matches the `stringToFind` value.

Comment: `If stringToSearch.Contains(stringToFind) Then ' ... :/ `

Answer (score 0):

> **Info : *This answer is obsolete and was based on the initial question of OP before the Edits.***

---

```
    "Anaheim Temp. 1-N/A".IndexOf("Temp") ' -> returns 8 = found at index 8 !
    "Cevera-N/A".IndexOf("Cevera") ' -> returns 0 = found at index 0 !
    "Cevera-N/A".IndexOf("Temp") ' -> returns -1 = not found !
    "Cevera-N/A".IndexOf("cevera") ' -> returns -1 = not found ! because it's lowercase !
```

I *do* agree with the comments above : you didn't provide what's the purpose of finding the specified word, or wether are your looking for a complex logic to confirm the presence of a specific identifer in a literal (Temp or Cereva or any other specific word in ANY provided literal sentence or formula)

We don't know what's the meaning of *"Anaheim Temp. 1-N/A"*, where did that came from, wether it's the value of a string variable or some literal expression of a formula entered in a text box...

You want to find "Temp" in *"Anaheim Temp. 1-N/A"*, **it's there already !!! How on earth would we have to search far away, while obviously *"Anaheim Temp. 1-N/A"* contains *"Temp"*** ?

And there are several ways to know if a String contains another String, but the usefull one depends on where the string *"Anaheim Temp. 1-N/A"* came from and why the string "Temp" should be found there but not "1" or "-N" or even "SantaMaria", and the purpose of searching that word for...

[You haven't tried anything](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) so far if I understand, while you want us to guess the logic behind.. XD

Answer (score 0):

***What the following code does is to extract Name components one by one until an invalid character is found.***

The Function input is a `String` which holds the literal names.
The output is a `List(Of String)` that contains each extracted name component.

Sample test -> Resulting Name Components

```
"Anaheim Temp. 1-N/A" -> [Anaheim],[Temp]
"Cevera-N/A"          -> [Cevera]
"Alex Orellana-NA"    -> [Alex],[Orellana]
"Marie J Blige ?"     -> [Marie],[J],[Blige]
"Marie J. Blige /vv"  -> [Marie],[J.],[Blige]
"José F. 1452"        -> [José],[F.]
"P. P. d'Arvor"       -> [P.],[P.],[d]
```

To make "P. P. d'Arvor" work, should include handling of ['] char, which I didn't.

(EDIT : It wasn't about Substrings.)

```
Public Function GetNames(ByVal SampleName As String) As List(Of String)
    Dim CharIndex As Integer = 0
    Dim NameStart As Integer = 0
    Dim NamesList As New List(Of String)

    ' Iterate the Chars from the left
    While CharIndex < SampleName.Length
        If Not Char.IsLetter(SampleName(CharIndex)) Then
            If Char.IsWhiteSpace(SampleName(CharIndex)) Then
                If CharIndex > NameStart Then
                    NamesList.Add(SampleName.Substring(NameStart, CharIndex - NameStart))
                End If
                NameStart = CharIndex + 1
            Else
                If (SampleName(CharIndex) = "."c) Then
                    ' This, to allow examples like "Angelina J.-N/A"
                    ' "Angelina" will be added first
                    ' then "J." (with the dot) will be added aswell.

                    If NameStart = (CharIndex - 1) Then
                        ' This simple check prevent the picking of
                        ' two consecutive dots like 
                        ' "Jarod R.. Solo" -> "Jarod" and "R." ("Solo" discarded)
                        ' "A. Leo D........" -> "A.", "Leo" and "D."
                        ' ". Andrew" -> "" (break immediately)

                        NamesList.Add(SampleName.Substring(NameStart, CharIndex - NameStart + 1))
                        NameStart = CharIndex + 1
                    Else
                        If NameStart < CharIndex Then
                            NamesList.Add(SampleName.Substring(NameStart, CharIndex - NameStart))
                        End If
                        Exit While
                    End If
                Else
                    If NameStart < CharIndex Then
                        NamesList.Add(SampleName.Substring(NameStart, CharIndex - NameStart))
                    End If

                    Exit While ' Discard the rest
                End If
            End If
        End If
        CharIndex = CharIndex + 1
    End While

    Return NamesList
End Function
```

Then use a Method like this :

```
Public Sub TestNames()
    Dim TestName As String
    Dim NameComponents As List(Of String)

    TestName = Microsoft.VisualBasic.InputBox("Enter Name") ' lazy me -_-
    NameComponents = GetNames(TestName)

    ' wanna see preview ? un-comment the following.
    'TestName = ""
    'For Each Word As String In NameComponents
    '    TestName = TestName + "[" + Word + "]" + Environment.NewLine
    'Next
    'MessageBox.Show(TestName)

    If NameComponents.Count > 1 Then ' You have at least two Names.
        ' The logic here is up to you
        ' FirstName = NameComponent.Item(0)
        ' LastName = NameComponent.Item(1)
    ElseIf NameComponents.Count > 0 Then ' You have only one Name.
        ' FirstName = NameComponent.Item(0)
        ' LastName = ""
    Else
        ' FirstName = "Unknown"
        ' LastName = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

EDIT : Fixed the multiple consecutive dots syndrome.